# Wine Install error ubuntu 12.04.1 32-bit

Tags: 12.04, wine, package-management, winetricks

When I try to install wine through terminal, it throws the error:

```
nits@nits-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.6-i386 : Depends: wine1.6 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then trying to fix broken packages it shows:

```
nits@nits-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wine1.6
Suggested packages:
  dosbox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wine1.6
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,160 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,047 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 301229 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wine1.6 (from .../wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wine', which is also in package wine1.6-i386 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am also not able to remove broken packages. What to do?
I have tried many solutions available on this topic but none of them is working.
Winetricks is installed, it wouldn't work without Wine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install wine1.6`

All credit goes to [this users post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154621&p=12693297#post12693297).

Comment: I could not overwrite the file using dpkg. So I tried deleting the file that causing problem.
It did the task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First i had to delete the broken package using:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.6_1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_i386.deb
```

Then tried to repair the broken packages again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Thank you everyone because my problem was solved by combining some solutions here.